# Filtering reoccuring values Power BI using DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table containing timestamps and Error codes from machines.

[image: Example of Reoccurring calculated column]

The machines will sometimes repeat the same error several times in a row but i only want to count these as one error. Thus I'm looking for a way to calculate if these errors is reoccurring and filter out these errors with some kind of filter.

I'm using DirectQuery so using EARLIER() to get the last error does not seem to work.

How should i filter these reoccuring errors?

Comment: What is your data source? Since you are using DQ, you can use functiona available in the database, e.g. LAG if your data source is SQL Server 2012 or newer.

Comment: My data source is an azure SQL database. Is it necessary to do this in the database? To my understanding LAG is the equivalent to EARLIER in power bi.

Comment: Well, you said that EARLIER doesn't work for you :) It isn't necessary to do this in the database - it's your choice where to do it.

Comment: It will probably be much easier to solve this in the database, ill try this tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey Nikolov assumed i needed to use PARTITION BY clause using the serial numbers for the machines.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *,
       (CASE WHEN error = 0 OR error = LAG(error, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY serial_nr ORDER BY event_time DESC)
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1
       END) AS error_is_new
FROM MyTable
```

I added a new column in my table containing whether an error is new.

I used error_is_new to only show the errors that were new.

Comment: Just one note, this code will give you 1's in `Reoccurring` for consecutive 0's in `Error` column. If you don't want to mark consecutive "success" as reoccurring, add `and error <> 0` to your case statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the database, Azure SQL Database supports [LAG function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so the query for loading the data to Power BI could be something like this:

```
declare @t table([Time] time, [Error] int)
insert into @t([Time], [Error]) values
    ('11:01', 0),
    ('12:12', 0),
    ('13:31', 4),
    ('14:50', 0),
    ('15:10', 4),
    ('15:20', 4),
    ('15:30', 4),
    ('15:40', 4),
    ('17:01', 1),
    ('18:09', 1),
    ('19:41', 0)


select
    t.[Time]
    , t.[Error]
    , IIF(t.[Error] <> 0 and LAG(t.[Error], 1) OVER(ORDER BY t.[Time]) = t.[Error], 1, 0) as Reoccuring
from @t t
order by t.[Time]
```

[image]

Please note, that the example doesn't show partitioning the data, e.g. by machine or something, because your sample data doesn't include that. If you need to do it, you must add [PARTITION BY clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-compare-values-within-partitions) to the LAG function. If you update your question with exact database schema, I will update my answer too.